# Ambiguity in decoding specific x87 FPU instructions

Tags: opcode, fpu, x87

I'm facing an ambiguous case with regard to decoding x87 FPU instructions. Take a look at the following instruction taken from page Page 3-380 of Vol 2A Intel's instruction set manual [1].

```
D9 /0    --> FLD m32fp --> Push m32fp onto the FPU register stack.
D9 C0+i  --> FLD ST(i) --> Push ST(i) onto the FPU register stack.
```

Both these instructions have the same single-byte base opcode `0xD9`. The first instruction has an extension opcode of `0x00`. The extension opcode will be specified in the 'reg' field of the ModR/M byte. But the second instruction is a 2 byte opcode with an 'Add to get register' feature. This means that:

```
D9 C0  --> FLD ST0  
D9 C1  --> FLD ST1  
(and so on)
```

I have a small issue with regard to differentiating these two instructions. A small example is:

Now, supposing I get the opcode sequence `"D9 C1"`. If I need to check if it's the instruction `"FLD m32fp"`, then I have to check if the 'reg' field of the ModR/M byte is 0x00 or not. If so, then it's indeed the instruction `"FLD m32fp"` being used.

The binary representation of `C1` is `"1100 0001"`. Assuming bit0 is LSB, then bit3-bit5 (inclusive) constitute the 'reg' field of the ModR/M byte `"C1"`. We see that it is indeed `0x00` (3 zeros).

So I map the opcode sequence `"D9 C1"` to the `"FLD m32fp"` instruction. Decoding further, we see that the operand actually becomes `"ecx"` in this case. But we see that `"FLD ST1"` also has opcode sequence `"D9 C1"`, and this is the actual instruction being used for that opcode sequence.

In essence, how can I be sure that the opcode sequence `"D9 C1"` corresponds to the instruction `"FLD ST1"` and not `"FLD ecx"`?

A very similar problems appears for the `"FMUL"` instruction too, since takes operands the same way as `"FLD"` here does.

[1] http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/243191.HTM

Thanks and Regards,
Hrishikesh Murali

Answer (score 6):

This is described in "A.2.6. Escape Opcode Instructions", the relevant part being:

> If the ModR/M byte is within
>   the range of 00H through BFH, bits 5, 4, and 3 of the ModR/M byte are used as an opcode extension, similar to the technique used for 1-and 2-byte opcodes (refer to Section A.2.5., “Opcode
>   Extensions For One- And Two-byte Opcodes”). If the ModR/M byte is outside the range of 00H
>   through BFH, the entire ModR/M byte is used as an opcode extension.

On to the question:

> Now, supposing I get the opcode sequence "D9 C1". If I need to check if it's the instruction "FLD m32fp", then I have to check if the 'reg' field of the ModR/M byte is 0x00 or not. If so, then it's indeed the instruction "FLD m32fp" being used.

When you encounter an x87 instruction you have to check whether the mod/rm byte is >= 0xC0 (corresponds to a mod field of 0b11 or 3) and in that case look it up in table Table A-10 (for D9). Looking there you see that `D9 C1 = FLD ST(0),ST(1)`.

When the mod/rm byte is < 0xC0 the table to use is A-9. `D9 01` (mod = 0b00, opcode extension (reg) = 0b000, rm = 0b001) is "FLD single-real", which looking at Table 2-2 turns out to be `fld dword [ecx]`.

As an aside there is no such instruction as "FLD ecx" since you can't load directly from an integer register onto the FPU stack.

Comment: Thanks! This did really help me understand it. :-) So this check '>=C0' is applicable for every instruction right? Or is it only applicable for FPU related instructions?

Comment: That's only for x87 instructions. You'll basically want to check first if `mod = 0b11` and in that case look-up the instruction in a 64 entry big table (modrm & 0x3F) otherwise use the reg field to determine the instruction and the rm field the operand.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with the "invlpg" instruction and the "rdtscp" instruction. "invlpg" has opcodes "0f 01" and extension as "07". "rdtscp" instruction has opcodes "0f 01 f9". If we check bits 3-5 of "f9", it resolves to 0x07. If I encounter "0f 01 f9", how do I know if it is "invlpg" (with modr/m as 0xf9) or "rdtscp"?

Comment: Use an updated version of [IA 64 and 32 ASDM Vol 2](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/manual/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) and consult table "A.4.2 Opcode Extension Tables".